# How to check if an Image is constant and retrieve its value?

Tags: google-earth-engine

I automatically created an image that should be constant, but I would like to make sure. How can I check if an image is constant and retreive its value ?

I tried to use:

```js
ee.Image(1).reduceRegion(ee.Reducer.mean())
```

But I get the following error:

> Image.reduceRegion: The default WGS84 projection is invalid for aggregations. Specify a scale or crs & crs_transform.

Is there a dedicated method or a trick ?

Comment: If you retrieve stats and min==max, it's constant. *Note that the title and body disagree.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error says, in order to preform an aggregation, you need to specify a projection and scale (and most likely a region) in which it should produce pixels.  Constant images don't have a scale or projection; they can produce pixels in any projection.

Comment: I just wanted ther ewwas a special reducer to check constent value. I assume not. thanks

Answer (score 1):

The value of an unmodified constant image is stored in the minimum and maximum of its `PixelType`, which can be accessed through the the [`ee.Image.bandTypes()`](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-image-bandtypes) method:

```js
var constant_img = ee.Image.constant(42).rename("test");

// Retrieve the pixel type of the "test" band
var pixel_type = ee.PixelType(constant_img.bandTypes().get("test"));
var value = pixel_type.minValue();
print(value);  // 42
```

To check if it's a constant, just compare the minimum and maximum values:

```js
// Compare the minimum and maximum values to see if it's a constant
var is_constant = pixel_type.maxValue().eq(pixel_type.minValue());
print(is_constant);  // 1 (true)
```

Note that modifying a constant image with another constant (e.g. adding or multiply by a number) will recalculate the correct pixel type values, but other operations like `sqrt` or `abs` will not, so this is an unreliable test if the image might be modified.

```js
var modified_pixel_type = ee.PixelType(constant_img.sqrt().bandTypes().get("constant"));
print(modified_pixel_type.minValue())  // -Infinity
print(modified_pixel_type.maxValue())  // Infinity
```

Of course you can also just check to see if the band name is `constant`, but if an image is modified by a non-constant value without changing the band name, it may incorrectly appear to be a constant.